# Why is the CSP script-src directive allowed in Chrome/Edge, but not in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, security, content-security-policy

I have this very simple CSP header, take note of the `script-src` directive:
`default-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; script-src-elem 'self' https://www.example.com 'unsafe-inline'; style-src https://www.example.com 'unsafe-inline'; manifest-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; worker-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; img-src 'self' data:;`

The header is accepted in both Chrome and Edge, but upon loading the app in Firefox, the following violation is generated: `Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).`

Why is Firefox not allowing the said directives?

Comment: Those directives are throwing all good practices to the junks ...

Comment: @Teemu, see it as a first draft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox does [not support](http://csplite.com/csp/test231/) the `script-src-elem` directive therefore it uses `script-src 'self';` which does not allow `'unsafe-inline'`.

Chrome supports the `script-src-elem` directive therefore it uses `script-src-elem 'self' https://www.example.com 'unsafe-inline';` which allows `'unsafe-inline'`.

I do not have Edge browser to test, but it's Chromium-based, so should support `script-src-elem`.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. Had to move the 'unsafe-inline' to the script-src directive, pretty unsafe.